# Problems in the selection sort loop

Tags: assembly, mips, nested-loops, selection-sort

I am having problems in the implementation of the selection sorting method in the assembly.

I still don't understand where I'm going wrong. Every help is welcome.

Maybe I'm wrong when allocating the number in the vector and then comparing it.

Follow the code in C # and then what I did in assembly.

```cs
public static void selecao(int[] vet)
{
   int i, j, min, temp;
   for (i = 0; i < vet.Length - 1; i++)
   {
      min = i;
   for (j = i + 1; j < vet.Length; j++)
   {
      if (vet[j] < vet[min])
      {
         min = j;
      }
   }
   temp = vet[i];
   vet[i] = vet[min];
   vet[min] = temp;
   }
}
```

Assembly

```
addi $t0, $zero, 0 
addi $t1, $zero, 0  
sub $s1, $s0, 1     
addi $s2, $zero, 0  
addi $t1, $zero, 0 
forS1:
slt $t2, $t0, $s1 (i < size v - 1)
beq $t2, $zero, fimForS1

addi $s2, $t0, 0

addi $t3, $t0, 1 
forS2:
slt $t4, $t3, $s0
beq $t4, $zero, fimForS2

add $s6, $s6, 1 
mul $t3, $t3, 4 
lw $s3, vetor($t3)      # vet[j]
mul $s2, $s2, 4
lw $s4, vetor($s2)      # vet[min]
slt $t5, $s3, $s4       # vet[j] < vet[min]
beq $t5, $zero, forS2
add $s7, $s7, 1 
add $s2, $t3, 0         # min = j
addi $t3, $t3, 1 
j forS2

fimForS2:
lw $t6, vetor($t1)      # vet[i]
mul $s5, $s2, 2         # posicao do vet[min]
lw $t7, vetor($s2)      # vet[min]  
addi $t8, $t6, 0        # temp = vet[i]
sw $t6, vetor($s2)          # vet[i] = vet[min];
sw $t7, vetor($t1)          # vet[min] = temp;
addi $t1, $t1, 4 
addi $t0, $t0, 1 

j forS1
```

Comment: For one, you stuck `j++` inside the nested `if` statement.  So you're doing `for(j=i+1; j<length; ) { if (...) { ... j++; } }`.

Comment: I don't know what `$s6` and `$s7` are doing, do you?

Comment: For another, you multiply min by 2, then don't use that result.  You want to shift by 2 or multiply by 4, and then use the result!

Comment: I didn't understand your explanation, sorry

Comment: $s6 and $s7 are the test and exchange counters, to know how many exchanges and tests have had

Comment: Your question doesn't say what happens when you run it; not a [mcve].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's look at the flow of control for a for-statement, first in pseudo code:

```
for ( int i = 0; i < n; i++ ) {
    ...body...
}
```

1. first we do `i=0`, once, outside the loop.
2. next, we start the loop with a check `i<n` to see if we are done with the loop,
3. next the code for `...body...`, and then
4. the increment `i++`, and finally,
5. to repeat the loop: go back to step 2.

When (using structure programming) we nest another control statement in the body of the loop, we still follow the same pattern, unchanged:

```
for ( int i = 0; i < n; i++ ) {
    if ( a < b ) {
         b = a;
    }
}
```

So, here the body is simply an if-statement.  Thus:

1. first we do `i=0`, once, outside the loop.
2. next, we start the loop with a check `i<n` to see if we are done with the loop,
3. next the `...body...`, which here is the if-statement:

   - test a < b and if not the case, skip ahead to 4.
   - capture b=a
4. the increment `i++`, and finally,
5. to repeat the loop: go back to step 2.

Do you see how whether the nested if-statement fires or doesn't fire, the proper next thing to do is the for-statement increment `i++`?

You have accidentally moved your `j++` increment to inside the then-part, inside the nested if-statement.  Your code is not following the proper pattern for nested control structures — the if-statement should not interfere with the for-statement that it is nested within.  So rather than doing `j++` regardless of what the if-statement does, you're doing `j++` only when the if-statement fires.  So, it is an incorrect translation of the pseudo code, and simply will not work properly.

Further below when you swap, you are using `vet[min]` but your array indexing is off.

---

See descriptions inline:

```
addi $t0, $zero, 0 
addi $t1, $zero, 0  
sub $s1, $s0, 1     
addi $s2, $zero, 0  
addi $t1, $zero, 0    <--- unnecessary, already done above
forS1:
slt $t2, $t0, $s1 (i < size v - 1)
beq $t2, $zero, fimForS1

addi $s2, $t0, 0

addi $t3, $t0, 1 
forS2:
slt $t4, $t3, $s0
beq $t4, $zero, fimForS2

add $s6, $s6, 1 
mul $t3, $t3, 4 
lw $s3, vetor($t3)      # vet[j]
mul $s2, $s2, 4
lw $s4, vetor($s2)      # vet[min]
slt $t5, $s3, $s4       # vet[j] < vet[min]

beq $t5, $zero, forS2   <--- this if statement skips the then part (good)
                             ***** but also skip the j++ (bad) *****

+------------------------------- this it the then part
add $s7, $s7, 1 
add $s2, $t3, 0         # min = j
addi $t3, $t3, 1        <--- this is j++
+-------------------------------
j forS2

fimForS2:
lw $t6, vetor($t1)      # vet[i]
mul $s5, $s2, 2         # posicao do vet[min]  <--- multiply by 2 (why 2??)
                                                    ***** $s5 is never used *****
lw $t7, vetor($s2)      # vet[min]         <--- here using $s2, min (bad)
                                           ***** you want min*4 instead *****
addi $t8, $t6, 0        # temp = vet[i]
sw $t6, vetor($s2)          # vet[i] = vet[min];
sw $t7, vetor($t1)          # vet[min] = temp;
addi $t1, $t1, 4 
addi $t0, $t0, 1 

j forS1
```